# How can I quickly change output of channel strip in Logic Pro X

Tags: recording, logic-pro

I'm wondering: how can I change an output of a track without deleting it (when you create a track in Logic, you can choose output).

### Example:

I have guitar on `Output 1+2` and I want to change it to `Output 3+4` how can I do it through mixer?

P.S: `macOS 10.12.4 Sierra`, `Logic Pro X 10.3.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to change the output using the **Channel Strip** in the **Inspector**, rather than in the mixer, as it has a less restricted view. In the picture below you can see the Inspector window, which is between the Library window and the main tracks window. This should open automatically; if you can't see this, press "I".

[image]

To change the Output of your Channel Strip (in the picture above it is "Inst 1"), click and hold or right-click where it says "Stereo Out". You can then select "Output 3-4" as in the picture below:

[image]

Just one thing to be aware of: Logic will *only* give you the option of selecting Output 3-4 if the device it is routed to is connected to your computer (wirelessly or with a lead). So, if Output 3-4 is routed by the OSX Aggregate Device to a bluetooth speaker, for instance, Logic will not show Output 3-4 if the bluetooth speaker is turned off, or not connected to your computer.

Comment: Just one small thing to add - you might not be able to see the "St Out" output button in the Mixer window unless you scroll up. That's why I suggest using the Inspector window instead. If you want to see a much bigger, easier to use separate Mixer window, press Cmd-2.